# Net new design visual QA methods? (not regression)

Tags: qa-process

I know that visual regression testing is done using tools like Applitools Eyes, or SmartBear CrossBrowserTesting, etc., based off comparing a baseline snapshot to a new image. But, I'm trying to determine a best process for net new pages, or whole redesigns.

I understand there's no replacement for human eyes, but developers are still provided with images (via Figma-to-Zeplin). Is it feasible to have those images added into existing Visual Regression tools as a baseline screenshot, instead of running the test to get baseline images?

Or are there other approaches that have streamlined / automated this process?

Comment: THe baseline image defers depending on the system , all this visual regression tools or library uses pixel  to pixel comparison. So if there is pixel or resolution difference The base line images changes, so thats why mainly we let the test take the baseline image after manual visual inspection

Comment: I understand all of this. My question is when the page has never existed before. If the test takes the baseline image of a brand new page, it's taking an untested baseline. The true baseline is sitting in another application - Zeplin. I want to be able to take that image and place it where the baseline would go.

Comment: Zeplin is a sketch tool. As PDHide said, the visual "testing" tools are sensible at the pixel level. Are your requirements to implement visual similar to the sketchs **at this level** of sensibility? If not, these tools will be more noise the useful. Anyhow, you will explore the first version of these pages - your testing can surely be supported by these tools in following iterations of the pages, after changes based on your first impressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never tried this before, but this (slightly old) [Applitools help doc](https://help.applitools.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007188231-Comparing-web-page-against-a-mockup-image) suggests converting the mockup to an image (if it isn't one already), sticking that in a shell web page, and then using their tools to make a comparison with the developed version.

It seems like [the reverse could also be done](https://help.applitools.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007188551-Image-Tester-Stand-alone-tool-for-images-comparison-and-PDF-validation) with their offering, taking a screenshot of the developed version and comparing that with the mockup.

Both seem kind of less than ideal processes imo. It might be worth reaching out to some of these vendors directly about if there are better options (I just tweeted at Applitools about this fwiw)

Comment: Twitter thread for reference - https://twitter.com/__grunet/status/1448815553326485506

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that what you are trying to do isn't right. There are major differences between the images from Figma and the snapshots from the website itself. Even for the same application, the stored snapshots will be different from one browser to another. You can't compare the chrome base snapshots VS the firefox snapshots, it will fail. Each browser gonna render the components in different ways. Even the OS is so important, If u generate your base snapshots in MaC OS and you tried to execute the same test suite in Linux OS, it will fail for the same reason. Each OS renders the images in a different way.

Even with the same OS and the same browsers, capture the snapshots in head mode and headless mode will lead to different base snapshots.

So, basically, to be able to do the visual snapshots, u have to guarantee that the test cases will always be executed using the same OS, Browser, Head or Headless mode.